# inserting dates into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple form which has a hidden field with a value of:

```
<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>
```

When i submit the form via my php processing script everything on the form goes into the database apart from the date.

here is my sql:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_reminders (dateofentry, ipaddress, type) VALUES ('$_POST[dateofentry]','$_POST[ipaddress]' ,'$_POST[type]')";
```

When i echo the date out on the processing page it shows fine.

I have setup the column in my database with the following:

```
 dateofentry date NOT NULL
```

Any ideas if there is anything wrong with the above?

Comment: add a var_dump of $_POST

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You need to use the appropriate method of your database library to escape your data prior to making the query.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong in the code that you have posted. I suggest you echo out `$sql` to assist in debugging the issue. That will narrow down where the problem is, that is, if it's a problem with the date literal supplied in the SQL statement, or whether the SQL statement is fine and the problem is on the MySQL server side.

Comment: i just just done a var dump and found out the following  ["dateofentry"]=> string(10) "02/11/2013". not sure what is going on as i have set the date as Y-m-d

Comment: Before you start smashing around with SQL queries by hand, please experiment with a [popular PHP framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/). The mistakes you're making here would be a lot harder to do if you were following best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Any dates inserted into MySQL must conform to [one of the formats that MySQL can parse](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) or it must be converted. [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is the preferred format, `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` typically.

If you used PDO:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_reminders (dateofentry, ipaddress, type) VALUES (:dateofentry, :ipaddress, :type)";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam(":dateofentry", strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(":ipaddress", $_POST['ipaddress'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(":type", $_POST['type']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();
```

Unless you're expecting the forms to take a very long time to process, it might make sense to supply the date at the time of query creation. If not, you can always put that `strtotime` call into your form instead.

Answer (score -1):

You must use this syntax to create your sql query :

`$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_reminders (dateofentry, ipaddress, type) VALUES ('".addslashes($_POST['dateofentry'])."','".addslashes($_POST['ipaddress'])."' ,'".addslashes($_POST['type'])."')";`

In your example, you're not wraping your index key with double quote...

And you really shouldn't put a php variable into a string, it's better to concatenate it.

Comment: Please don't post answers that are enormous security holes. You should *never* insert `$_POST` data directly into a query string. Concatenating vs. interpolating isn't even the issue, it isn't "better" at all. They're the same.

Comment: Someone already talked about security, it's easier to explain the error without adding complexity into my explanation. Moreover, my answer is about his problem, to help fixing it, not to teach him how to be secure. No Period.

Comment: the above code is purely for testing and would just like to know if anyone can see any problems, not to be slammed about my coding skills.

Comment: "Concatenating vs. interpolating isn't even the issue" So you're saying that's it's better to ignore if php will parse the string to replace variables in the good way? That's maybe why {$_POST[key]} can be used... I'm just giving an advice here, what's the point to comment my answer to tell me if it's nice or not, you should rather help him and give YOUR answer.

Comment: Your answer can address the problem without containing hazardously bad code. I mean like lose-your-job-and-destroy-your-career bad. Escape it or don't post it. Is this too much to ask?

Comment: @danyo I don't mean to single you out for abuse here, but that sort of style is not just a matter of preference. It's scary bad. You should never do that, period, not even for testing, if only because "test" code has a way of sneaking into production when you're not looking. If you're even thinking about writing queries that way, you need to read up on [SQL injection problems](http://bobby-tables.com/) before you do anything else.